# how can i use jalali calendar (persian calendar) in react-big-calendar

Tags: reactjs, typescript, momentjs, react-big-calendar

I create a project with react-big-calendar ([code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-big-calendar-m5l91j)) and I want to use **jalali** calendar in this project instead of georgian.

I found a [jalali-react-big-calnedar repo](https://github.com/fingerpich/jalali-react-big-calendar) but its based on old version of react-big-calendar.

how can i change the default lib calendar to jalali?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you may be able to use the [momentLocalizer](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/props--localizer) using a decorated `moment` with [moment-jalaali](https://github.com/jalaali/moment-jalaali), and the proper [culture](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/props--culture) prop. Being unfamiliar with the culture used, you may also require the [rtl](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/props--right-to-left) prop.

Again, not sure if this would work for you or not. Think I would fork the [Big Calendar CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-example-v9wdyd) and do some testing first, if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried your idea in this CodeSandBox :https://codesandbox.io/s/jalaali-big-calendar-ek46xq But there is a problem in adding and displaying the event in the month and agenda... what should i do?

Comment: Looking at your CodeSandbox, your issue is your treatment of `start` and `end` dates. Big Calendar documentation on [Understanding Dates](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/story/guides-understanding-dates--page) explains how all dates must be JS Date objects. By [forking your example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jalaali-big-calendar-forked-4f63mx?file=/src/JalaaliBigCalendar.tsx), changing the dates to true JS Dates, and changing them to 2022, I was able to see the event in the month view (I don't read Persian, so took a min to figure out that much in nav).

Comment: Thanks i saw your forked sandbox. The first problem is when we add an event on `month view` it added in a random day i guess. And the second problem is when an event added, the event is shown in agenda without time ( allDay: "همه ی روز" )

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
If I understood correctly, you want to change your calendar to Farsi;  This is a React component for Khayyam's calendar. (Jalali):
*/

const Jalali = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    const option = {
        weekday: "long",
        year: "numeric",
        month: "numeric",
        day: "numeric",
        };
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {date.toLocaleDateString("fa-IR", option)}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Jalali;
```

Comment: That's not what i meant. I wanted to make a jalali calendar with react-big-calendar lib. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MarziehMousavi It might help if you made it more clear which problem you are actually trying to solve. Please read [asking questions}(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for pointers.